# How to start two asynctask in a single button click on one activity android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing an application in which i need to call two `AsyncTask`s in a single button click in the same activity. How to do that?

Any help appreciated. Please provide some code also.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing fancy, just start them one by one, they are async anyway.

```
private class TaskA<A,B,C> extends AsyncTask{}
private class TaskB<A,B,C> extends AsyncTask{}

onClick(View v){
    (new TaskA()).execute();
    (new TaskB()).execute();
}
```

Comment: @aditi Yes its the way. i used once like the above. its simple. You are right Xandy.